# linphonec and h264 codec

Tags: h.264, linphone

GUI version of linphone is configured with h264 codec and works well. But linphoneC (command line version), which is in the folder with linphone, in response to the command "vcodec list" returns only "0: VP8 (90000) enabled" and not work with h264. How to configure linphoneC to work with h264? Thank you!